# Tesseract: Short words are not detected

Tags: tesseract

I'm trying to detect names with Tesseract 3.02.

The detection works perfectly without any error on long names like "Peggy Scott-Adams" and "Jonathan Miller".

However, if the names are too short, like "Jim Lee" the ocr detection won't work any more.

Note how the image looks like:
The first name stands in the first line, the last name stands in the second line. Nothing else on the image.

What can I do?

Comment: Can I try to combine images of ten names into one?

Comment: Have you tried using different page segmentation modes?

Comment: Probably good idea for others but didn't help in my case

Comment: Can you provide a sample image?